# differences between each row for all columns setting index column

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, difference

I have this pandas data frame named ndf2:

```
       ds        sc
0    1000  0.516512
1    1100  0.542311
2    1200  0.552666
3    1300  0.567540
4    1400  0.585531
5    1500  0.595928
6    1600  0.601140
7    1700  0.602802
8    1800  0.605209
9    1900  0.616163
10   2000  0.627078
11   2100  0.632283
```

I want to calculate de difference between each row for both columns setting the index column:

```
ndf2.set_index().diff()
```

Is giving me this error:

> TypeError: set_index() missing 1 required positional argument: 'keys'

How can I change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need only [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html):

```
print (df.diff())
       ds        sc
0     NaN       NaN
1   100.0  0.025799
2   100.0  0.010355
3   100.0  0.014874
4   100.0  0.017991
5   100.0  0.010397
6   100.0  0.005212
7   100.0  0.001662
8   100.0  0.002407
9   100.0  0.010954
10  100.0  0.010915
11  100.0  0.005205
```

Or add column names as parameter to [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html):

```
print (df.set_index('ds').diff())
            sc
ds            
1000       NaN
1100  0.025799
1200  0.010355
1300  0.014874
1400  0.017991
1500  0.010397
1600  0.005212
1700  0.001662
1800  0.002407
1900  0.010954
2000  0.010915
2100  0.005205
```